getting "Upgrade Required" when hosting on AWS ECS why?
i am trying to host my website on AWS ECS Fargate
i am using django rest framework on the backend and react on the frontend
currently i am just trying to run the appication backend
i have three container nignx, django and postgresql
i created a task defenition and ran a service using it
when i try to access the website it shows 'Upgrade Required'
i checked the logs and it shows
2024/06/09 18:50:31 [error] 23#23: *5 connect() to [2600:f0f0::1]:8000 failed (101: Network is unreachable) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[2600:f0f0::1]:8000/favicon.ico", host: "3.25.91.93", referrer: "http://3.25.91.93/" c1a79d3ae2ec4ed1b5380ea27ac8ef00

2024/06/09 18:50:31 [warn] 23#23: *5 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[2600:f0f0::1]:8000/favicon.ico", host: "3.25.91.93", referrer: "http://3.25.91.93/"   c1a79d3ae2ec4ed1b5380ea27ac8ef00

June 10, 2024 at 00:20 (UTC+5:30)   127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jun/2024:18:50:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 426 16 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"    c1a79d3ae2ec4ed1b5380ea27ac8ef00

June 10, 2024 at 00:18 (UTC+5:30)   127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jun/2024:18:48:11 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 426 16 "http://3.25.91.93/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"

i am new to aws and ecs.  i also set up ecs service connect and added three service to a namespace
like
Service Connect Service - 1, Port alias  db-5432-tcp, Discovery   postgres, DNS    postgres, Port    5432
Service Connect Service - 2, Port alias  backend-8000-tcp, Discovery   backend, DNS    backend, Port    8000
Service Connect Service - 3, Port alias  nginx-80-tcp, Discovery   nginx, DNS    nginx, Port    80
can someone help me?
